# Crash when using keras ? Or when loading a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hi when I'm running my code with CNN_1() inside it works fine and crashes (Kerniel died in Spyder, computing endlessly in shell) when I try to load my model with keras.models.load_model().

And when I don't use CNN_1() directly I just compute all my functions in an interactive python and then compute CNN_1() it crashes. I don't see any difference between executing everything as a group or individually, but there seems to be.

I was thinking that it may be caused by a wrong version of something but I check on everything things and it's all ok.
Here is my code and at the end my config.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os, os.path
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

from keras import layers, models
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras.backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mask_make(xt):
    t = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))(xt)
    t= layers.UpSampling2D()(t)

    bool_mask = K.greater_equal(xt,t)
    mask = K.cast(bool_mask,dtype='float32')

    mask_input= layers.Input(tensor=mask)
    return mask_input

def C_for_softmax(x):
    return K.sum(K.exp(x))

def inv_softmax(x,C):
    return K.log(x)+K.log(C_for_softmax(x))

def CNN_1_layers(inputs):

    #block 1
    x = layers.Conv2D(16,5,5, activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,1),border_mode='valid')(inputs)
    m.append(mask_make(x))
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    #block 2
    x = layers.Conv2D(32,5,5, activation='relu',border_mode='valid')(x)
    m.append(mask_make(x))
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    #block 3
    x = layers.Conv2D(64,6,6, activation='relu',border_mode='valid')(x)
    m.append(mask_make(x))
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    #block 4
    x = layers.Conv2D(128,5,5, activation='relu',border_mode='valid')(x)
    m.append(mask_make(x))
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    #block sortie
    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(10,4,4, activation='relu',border_mode='valid')(x)
    x = layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,1,10))(x)
    C.append(C_for_softmax(x))
    x = layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')(x)

    return x

def CNN_1():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128,128,1),name="input_CNN")
    layers_CNN = CNN_1_layers(inputs)
    model_conv = models.Model(inputs,layers_CNN,name='CNN_1')
    model_conv.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    model_conv.summary()
    return model_conv

def apprentissage(model,nb_epoch=100):
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="CNN_1.h5",monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto')
    early= EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0,patience=100,verbose=1,mode='auto')
    hist= model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=(test_X,test_y), callbacks=[early, checkpoint])
    model = models.load_model("CNN_1.h5")
    return hist

def load():
    model = models.load_model("CNN_1.h5")
    return model
```

When I compute every def there is no error then if I call CNN_1() it crashes.
But if I put CNN_1() at the end of the code out of a def and compute everythings together it works and crashes when I run load().

My config:

Keras 2.3.1

tensorflow 2.1.0

CUDA 10.1

CUDNN 7.6.4.38

Python 3.6.8 (with anaconda)

Nvidia driver 430.64

4 GPU TITAN X

If you need any other thing feel free to ask.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just reboot the computer a second time and it "works" with Spyder.
The first time I train or I load the model everything's fine but the next action using the model make my kernel crash.
For example when I do model.fit() it works then I do model=models.load() it crashes.

It keeps crashing ("Segmentation fault (core dumped)") when I run the code in a shell (just compiling the models).